# Problem trying to select only one line or one point (from json data) on OpenLayers Vue 3 js

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, openlayers, geojson

Using Vue JS 3, I’m trying to select on an OpenLayers map one point or one line displayed from two json files (respectively with all points and all lines).
Basically, I’m trying to replicate the Vue3 OpenLayers [example code](https://vue3openlayers.netlify.app/componentsguide/interactions/select/#usage).

While, in the OpenLayers example, the user can select by moving the mouse one part of the features displayed (one polygon or one point), my pointer select all features when moving (all lines OR all points).

My template is defined as following :

```js
<template>
  <ol-map :loadTilesWhileAnimating="true" :loadTilesWhileInteracting="true" style="height:400px" :key="map">

    <ol-view ref="view" :center="center" :rotation="rotation" :zoom="zoom" :projection="projection"
      @zoomChanged="zoomChanged" @centerChanged="centerChanged" @resolutionChanged="resolutionChanged"
      @rotationChanged="rotationChanged" />

    <ol-zoom-control />

    <ol-scaleline-control />

    <ol-tile-layer>
      <ol-source-osm />
    </ol-tile-layer>

    <ol-interaction-select @select="featureSelected" :condition="selectCondition">
      <ol-style>
(…)
      </ol-style>
    </ol-interaction-select>

    <ol-vector-layer>
      <ol-source-vector :format="geoJson" :projection="projection">
        <!-- Affichage des arrêts et mouvements -->
        <div v-else>
          <!-- afficher l'ensemble des mouvements  -->
          <ol-feature>
            <ol-geom-multi-line-string :coordinates="mouvementCoordinates"></ol-geom-multi-line-string>
            <ol-style>
(…)            </ol-style>
          </ol-feature>
          <!-- afficher l'ensemble des arrêts  -->
          <ol-feature>
            <ol-geom-multi-point :coordinates="arretCoordinates"></ol-geom-multi-point>
            <ol-style>
(…)
            </ol-style>
          </ol-feature>
        </div>

      </ol-source-vector>
    </ol-vector-layer>

  </ol-map>
</template>
```

The props received (geoJsonArretList, geoJsonMouvementList) are of type :

```json
{
type : "FeatureCollection", 
features: Array(60)
0: {type: "Feature", geometry:{...}, properties: {...}}
1: ...
}
```

The information sent to the template (arretCoordinates, mouvementCoordinates) are built as followed :

```js
arretCoordinates() {
      return this.geoJsonArretList.features.map(feature => feature.geometry.coordinates);
    },
    mouvementCoordinates() {
      return this.geoJsonMouvementList.features.map(feature => feature.geometry.coordinates);
    },
```

Apart from selecting with pointer move one line or one point, I would like to display with a console.log only some properties from it.

I tried with and without the selectInteractionFilter from the OpenLayers example, adapted to my props. I also tried removing one of the two ol-feature, for example, without all multilines keeping only multi-points.

Comment: If you don't want to combine all the geometries into a single multigeometry feature the easiest way would be to use two vector layers with url sources as in the example.  If the data did not come from a url create data urls from your data objects and inject those, for example `'data:,' + JSON.stringify(geoJsonArretList)`

Comment: Thank you Mike ! Unfortunately it didn't work : when I called my function, it made the map disappear ... But I do think you are right thinking the problem relies in the multigeometry feature. I'll modify my code to add two vector layers and repost if it works !

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from the geom-multi-line-string / geom-multi-point feature : since it was considered as only one feature being only one multi-line (built from multiple geom-line-string), it was displayed and thus selectable as one element.

The following changes made it work : creating a loop (v-for element) inside the ol-feature element and adding each line as a single line-string or as a single point if point : geom-line-string / geom-point.

```
<template>
  <ol-map :loadTilesWhileAnimating="true" :loadTilesWhileInteracting="true" style="height:400px" :key="map">

    <ol-view ref="view" :center="center" :rotation="rotation" :zoom="zoom" :projection="projection"/>

    <ol-zoom-control />

    <ol-scaleline-control />
    <ol-layerswitcherimage-control />


    <ol-tile-layer>
      <ol-source-osm />
    </ol-tile-layer>

    <ol-interaction-select @select="featureSelected" :condition="selectCondition">
      <ol-style>
        (...)
      </ol-style>
    </ol-interaction-select>

    <div v-if="tableauFilter.length">
      <ol-vector-layer v-if="mouvementTableauFiltre" v-for="(ensembleMouvement, index) in mouvementTableauFiltre"
        :key="index">
        <ol-source-vector :format="geoJson" :projection="projection" >
          <!-- Affichage des arrêts et mouvements pour chaque filtration -->
          <!-- pour chaque filtre existant, afficher l'ensemble des mouvements obtenu pour chaque filtre -->
          <ol-feature v-for="(feature) in ensembleMouvement.features">
            <ol-geom-line-string
              :coordinates="feature.geometry.coordinates"></ol-geom-line-string>
            <ol-style>
              (...)
            </ol-style>
          </ol-feature>
        </ol-source-vector>
      </ol-vector-layer>
      <!-- pour chaque filtre existant, afficher l'ensemble des arrêts obtenu pour chaque filtre -->
      <ol-vector-layer v-if="arretTableauFiltre" v-for="(ensembleArret, index) in arretTableauFiltre" :key="index">
        <ol-source-vector :format="geoJson" :projection="projection">
          <ol-feature v-for="(feature) in ensembleArret.features">
            <ol-geom-point
              :coordinates="feature.geometry.coordinates"></ol-geom-point>
            <ol-style>
              (...)
            </ol-style>
          </ol-feature>
        </ol-source-vector>
      </ol-vector-layer>
    </div>
  </ol-map>
</template>
```